# Number animation in geogebra?

Tags: math-software

[image]

Is there a way to animate this "triangle" in Geogebra so that the rows are expanding from the top to the bottom?

Answer (score 2):

Slider n (from 0 to 10) then:

```
a = floor(123456789 / 10^(10 - n))
text1 = a + " × 9 + " + n + " = " + (9a + n)
```

Comment: 0 to 10 (instead of 1 to 10).

Comment: Thanks, changed :)